# Corsa C electric power steering ECU 12V power polarity

Tags: power-steering, electronic-control-module, opel, gm, corsa

I need to know the power polarity of Corsa C Electric Power Steering ECU 12V power connector. I suppose the power is the right connector in following photo (it has 2 flat pins vertically aligned):

[image]

If someone knows what is the left connector for that would be nice too. The torque sensor and DC motor are connected from the other side of the unit (not pictured) - I am not interested in those.

Here is the ECU part number:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can probably find the ground with an Ohm meter ... check for continuity between each of those two pins and the casing on the unit. If one has continuity, that's your ground.

Comment: So I checked and there is no continuity between either of the pins and the casing... pictures of spare units on the net with cables cut show the top cable being red (+) but it would be nice to have this confirmed.

Comment: Don't you have the plug which goes in there? If so, test it for power off of the side you believe is the power side. Test it with the car running, as I doubt it would be powered otherwise.